# Why wont mocha wait for chai as promised to finish?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, promise, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test a web application using selenium, mocha and chai-as-promised. I cannot seem to get mocha to wait for the chai-as-promised assertions to be resolved. My testing code looks like this:

```
var selenium = require('selenium-webdriver')
var By = selenium.By
var chai = require('chai')
var cap = require('chai-as-promised')
chai.use(cap)
expect = chai.expect

describe('Test Group', function() {
  var driver
  before(function() {
    driver = new selenium.Builder()
      .withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.chrome())
      .build()
    driver.getWindowHandle()
  })

  after(function() {
    driver.sleep(500).then(function() {
      driver.quit()
    })
  })

  describe('Authentication', function() {
    describe('#login redirect', function() {
      it('should redirect to /users/login when not logged in', function() {
        driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/')
        driver.sleep(500).then(function() {
          return expect(driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.contain('WONT CONTAIN THIS')
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

The test always passes, despite the assertion being unable to. The tests return these errors aswell:

```
  Test Group
    Authentication
      #login redirect
        ✓ should redirect to /users/login when not logged in


  1 passing (34ms)

(node:24883) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login' to include 'WONT CONTAIN THIS'
(node:24883) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to make `mocha` tests asynchronous.

1. Using the first parameter of the test function: `done`.
2. Returning a promise

Here you can read more about [Mocha Asynchronous Tests](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

In your case, you are already using promises so the easiest solution would be to return your promise. Something like this:

```
  it('should redirect to /users/login when not logged in', function() {
    driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/')
    return driver.sleep(500).then(function() { // <------- return this promise
      return expect(driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.contain('WONT CONTAIN THIS')
    })
  })
```

This is also relevant to your `after` function. The way it is written now, the `after` function will complete before the inner promise resolves. You could make it async like so:

```
  after(function() {
    return driver.sleep(500).then(function() {
      driver.quit()
    })
  })
```

Note that if `driver.quit()` returns a promise, you probably should `return` that as well.